# ObjectId changing to string in find() query in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
data = self.mongo['customer'].find(query, projection)
```

Data has different users.

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('598b5de38161a821188f1a7c'), 'first name': 'first name', 'last Name': 'last name'},
{'_id': ObjectId('671239hdajsn623hjt6719hs'), 'first name': 'second name', 'last Name': 'second name'}]
```

It is showing when sending as a Response

> TypeError: Object of type ObjectId is not JSON serializable

I want to change ObjectId to string in the query itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert or modify data in any form, you have to make use of MongoDB aggregation.

Use `$toString` accumulator to convert ObjectID type to string in `$project` stage

```
projection["_id"] = {"$toString": "$_id"}

data = self.mongo['customer'].aggregate([
  {
    "$match": query
  },
  {
    "$project": projection
  },
])
```

Comment: I have explored this aggregate we can do this by aggregate but do we have anything in the .find() query because I am not sure if aggregate takes more time than find.

Comment: No, its not possible using find command, since it cant do anything beyond returning the actual document. The aggregation query will take almost the same time as the find command if not equal. You wont be able to spot the difference in performance given that the `query` options are indexed or the number of documents in the collection is fewer, same as that of the find query considerations.

Comment: It is more expensive to query with aggregate than find but it is still better to use aggregate than find where most of the cases have to do more operations.